# Proper use of CFLOCK in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, race-condition

So i'm a bit confused. I've got a race condition happening with an intranet application.

Intermittently users are getting the wrong IDs and it's causing some minor hiccups with showing who created posts and events and what not.

my problem is I've set up some cflock tags to try to prevent this but they don't appear to be working; Now i'm wondering if i'm using them correctly.

Our staff are technically challenged.... We auto log them into the intranet application once they are logged into their windows session(not really secure, i know but it doesn't matter here).

then under **Staff permissions check** i check to see if they have an account and if they do i return the ID that matches their session.name. Then through out their session that ID is used to track and identify who they are and what they do as well as their access level.

Now I've added a cflock at the top of this because i was getting users with mixed up IDs but it doesn't seems to have worked. Should i be placing the lock around the calls in application.cfc or in the WhosOnline.cfc itself around the query that pulls all this info? I've gone through the docs and maybe i'm missing something or i just don't get it. Below is a snippet from my application.cfc

```
<cffunction
        name="OnSessionStart"
        access="public"
        returntype="void"
        output="false"
        hint="I fire when a new session begins.">

        <cflock scope = "Application"
                timeout = "10" type = "Exclusive">

            <!--- Set up session variables. --->
            <CFSET SESSION.domain = "GL\">            
            <cfset SESSION.LoggedIn = false />
            <cfset SESSION.Name = "#REPLACENOCASE(AUTH_USER,'#session.domain#','')#" />
            <cfset session.filestore = "/documents/">
            <CFSET session.hostname="#CreateObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress").getByName("#cgi.REMOTE_HOST#").getHostName()#">

            <CFSET session.todayodbc = #createodbcdate(now())#>
            <CFSET SESSION.usercheck = false>

            <cfset session.securityRedirect = "/securitywarning.cfm" >

            <!--- Staff permissions check --->
            <CFSET objNewUser = CreateObject("component", "cfc.WhosOnline")>
            <cfset qryNewUser = #objNewUser.newusercheck(session.name)#>
            <cfset session.staffid = #qryNewUser#>

            <!---Staff Name --->
            <cfset objName = CreateObject("component", "cfc.WhosOnline")>
            <cfset qryName = #objName.staffName(session.staffid)#>
            <cfset session.StaffName = '#qryName#'>


            <cfset session.root = "E:\web-sites\intranet2\">

            <!--- Return out. --->
            <cfreturn />

        </cflock>
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: I think the problem might be that your `cflock` scope is `application` instead of `session`. You should be locking the scope you are changing. Also, make sure to varscope any local variables (like `objNewUser`, `qryNewUser`). Variables that aren't varscoped aren't thread-safe

Comment: What variables scope do you acess in the functions `newusercheck` and `staffName`?

Comment: Also, if you are not in the habit of properly scoping all function local variables with `var/Local` (as in the code above), there could be problems elsewhere in the application as well.

Comment: All good points so far.  I'mma add some probably more obvious stuff.  You should also scope, and question the value of, cgi.auth_user.  if this is the only place session.staffid is set, the problem is the result of the newusercheck function or the object it's a part of, which could also be an input problem.  When there's a mismatched ID, does it happen for the entire session?  Check your session chain and cookie handling.  Does this function really only run once per session?

Comment: Probably not related to your question, but creating two objects with the same component is inefficient.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the flu knocked me out for a day.
To answer some questions my variables in the functions are not scoped(wraps knuckles).  I thought all vars in CF had a default scope of local so i never bothered unless i had to explicitly specify a scope like form.

After doing some research i read the 'OnSessionStart' function will lock itself to the scope when it's initiated so i'm going to remove the cflock totally  .

Comment: I've also been able to recreate the problem once!  When i saw i had an improper userID i was able to recreate the problem but upon page refresh it corrected itself and never happened again.  The session length is 30 mins so it shouldn't be running any of this code on page refresh unless the session has expired, right?

I'm going to look into how to check my session chain and verify the function only runs once per session. No cookies are used, it's all stored in a user session.